# In Texture Paint the colors are not connected

Tags: texturing, texture-paint-mode

I was wondering why in *Texture Paint* the colors are not connected? There is a gap between the colours here and I don't understand why. I appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: What have you done to try to fix it? Have you tried painting that strip yet?

Comment: Acutally, I'm also wondering what exactly you did and what do you think why there is a gap and what you tried to get rid of it. Do I understand the question correctly as to why there is a white strip amidst the red color? Then the question would be: how did you get the red color onto the object? And did you try to do that on the white strip as well? Or did you maybe try to paint in the _Image Editor_ on the left because there you can clearly see the strips as welland try to paint on them. And I see a vertex group as mask to the right - did you exclude those vertices from texture painting?

Comment: just provide your blend file to stop questions in comments, to attract more people and to get precise help.

Comment: Hello, somi, and welcome. I think it would help us to see the UV map, and I'm curious about the _Mask_ modifier, and its vertex-group .. better yet, as @Chris has suggested, follow the instructions on https://blend-exchange.com/, and edit the resulting link into your question.